# (python) why the result of this code not in right order?

Tags: python, for-loop

input:

```
D = {"apple":44, "cherry":"game"}
for x in D:
    print(x, D[x])
    print(str(x) + ": "+ str(D[x]))
```

output:

```
apple 44
apple: 44
cherry game
cherry: game
```

Isn't this supposed to be outputted like this in right order?

```
apple 44
cherry game
apple: 44
cherry: game
```

Comment: The output is exactly how it is supposed to be given the logic in your code. In each iteration of the loop you are using x and corresponding value in two print statements.

Comment: If you want the second output then you will need two loops one after each other

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried tracing through the code line-by-line? Make sure you understand how and when loops actually repeat their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X start out as apple the first iteration and then goes to cherry the secound iteration

Answer (score 0):

In each loop you:

1. print the label and its value;
2. print the label converted to sting and its value converted to string.

So in the first cycle you have prints on element "apple":44, and in the second one prints on "cherry":"game".

The output is totally right.